# How to control the concurrency in flask?

Tags: python, multithreading, gunicorn

I have developed the Flask application, live on AWS EC2 Instance and i have increased the number of worker and threads like below:

```
gunicorn.... --worker=2 --thread=4
```

What i understand so far from sites that it may create the 4 parallel request for single worker in 1 core of CPU and same for other. Eventually you will be getting 8 requests per second.
As i am multithreading so i was bit hesitated that my app responses should not get mixed up or does not overwrite some other requests results as i am saving some things on disk too:
Here is brief overview of app

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.route('/route1'):
    #ML Model processing
    return jsonify{'Result'}
app.route('/route2'):
    #ML Model 2 processing
    #Save image to folder and then process ml model on it 
    return jsonify{'Result'}
```

**Note: Here i have created only single folder which will gonna overwrite image for each request.**

So to not get mixed up for any results not for just this one but also for first one , I want to know what is good ?
I have heard about Lock, Semaphores but what you suggest ?. Which method is best ? I think i am doing concurrency and I want to take control